# How to make simple carousel using functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone make me simple, easy to understand JS for carousel. I don't really understand usage of "this" so, can you explain what is going on?

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
.no {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="yes"></div>
  <div class="no"></div>
  <div class="no"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>left</li>
    <li>right</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="yes"></div>
  <div class="no"></div>
  <div class="no"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>left</li>
    <li>right</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `this` usually is a javascript keyword.. So you need to show us some `js` to make you understand the part of code which you didn't

Comment: don't see any reference to 'this' in the provided code. Am I missing something ?

Comment: It doesn't seem like Google to me... is this Google?

Comment: anyways here you go : http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Answer (score -3):

```
div:nth-child(1) {
 background-color: red;
}

that means this CSS apply only on all first child div whose parent is <div> tag

First parent div's inside four child , three div and one <Ul> so basically according to our CSS it apply it on first div (color red).

second and third <div> block is hidden due to class ".no" containing display none property
```

Comment: I have explained you how it work. You can't get it ?

Comment: *don't ..ahh.. okay did you even get the question? Why are you explaining the css?

Comment: What you want. i will make a jquery function for that instead of css. but tell me is there fix div or n numbers of div

Comment: I asked for JS for carousel, that means by pressing "left" or "right" changes "activity" of divs (siblings of that "ul" where the left or right were pressed) and have no influence on other red square. For example: pressing "right" below left square changes his background color to blue, pressing again changes to green, pressing "left" under same square returns to blue, pressing "left" again returns to red